# Given a family $\mathfrak{F}$ for sets, when are $\bigcup \mathfrak{F}$ and $\bigcap \mathfrak{F}$ empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove, disprove, or give a counterexample:
>
> - Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be a family of sets. Then $\bigcup \mathfrak{F}=\varnothing$ iff $A=\varnothing$ for all $A \in \mathfrak{F}$.
> - Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be a family of sets. Then $\bigcap \mathfrak{F}=\varnothing$ iff $A=\varnothing$ for all $A \in \mathfrak{F}$.

I was thinking about using the following:

- $x \in\bigcup\mathfrak{F}$ if and only if $(\exists A\in\mathfrak{F})$$(x\in A)$
- $x \in\bigcap\mathfrak{F}$ if and only if $(\forall A\in\mathfrak{F})$$(x\in A)$

Are these the correct definitions to apply? If so, how can I go about using them if these two can in fact be proved?

Comment: Your definitions are correct :) For the first one, suppose one of the sets is not empty, what can you deduce? As for the second one try to find a counterexample

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use these definitions but also maybe the fact that Then $\cup \mathfrak{F}=\emptyset \implies \cup \mathfrak{F}\subseteq\emptyset$. Now, $A \subseteq B \iff (x \in A \implies x \in B)$. Co combining this with your definition we have that

$(\exists A\in\mathfrak{F})$$(x\in A) \implies x \in \emptyset$. This is obviously a contradiction. So the precedent cannot work. There can be no set $A \in \mathfrak F$ with an element $x$. Therefore $A = \emptyset \;\; \forall A \in \mathfrak F$. The converse is easier to prove. $A = \emptyset \implies \bigcup A = \emptyset$.

For the second case we have  $(\forall A\in\mathfrak{F})$$(x\in A) \implies \cap \mathfrak{F} \subseteq \varnothing$ also leading to a contradiction. The negation of the precedent yields that $\exists A \in \mathfrak{F}$ such that $x \not \in A \;\; \forall x$. This says $A  = \emptyset $ for some $A \in \mathfrak{F}$. The converse again is easy to prove.

Comment: For the second one I don't believe we must have $\exists A\in\mathfrak{F},\,A=\emptyset$. In fact, if you take $\mathfrak{F}=\{\{x\}\, :\, x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ then $\forall A\in\mathfrak{F},\,A\neq\emptyset$ yet the intersection of any two distinct elements of $\mathfrak{F}$ is $\emptyset$.